# Wordpress navmenu not working

Tags: php, css, wordpress

Hi im trying to get mainmenu working, but i guess i do something wrong here is the code:

I am using bootstrap and linked it like this:

```
<link href="<?php bloginfo('stylesheet_directory'); ?>/assets/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

Anyone knows how to get this right?

```
    <!-- HEADER 
  ===========================================-->

    <header class="site-header" role="banner">

        <!-- NAVBAR 
     ===========================================-->

        <div class="navbar-wrapper">

            <div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation">

                <div class="container">
                    <div id="navbar" class="navbar-collapse collapse">
                        <ul class="nav navbar-nav">

                            <li class="dropdown">
                                <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Dropdown <span class="caret"></span></a>
                                <ul class="dropdown-menu">

                                </ul>
                            </li>
                        </ul>

                        <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                        </ul>

                    </div>

                    <?php
    wp_nav_menu( array(
        'menu'              => 'primary',
        'theme_location'    => 'primary',
        'container'         => 'div',
        'container_class'   => 'navbar-collapse collapse',
        'container_id'      => 'navbar',
        'menu_class'        => 'nav navbar-nav'

    ) );
?>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </header>
```

Updated version

Comment: `menu` in the options is missing when you called wp_nav_menu

Comment: Please refer here https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_nav_menu/

Comment: What do you mean exactly? Something like this:
     'menu'              => 'primary',

Comment: yes like this 'menu' => 'your menu name or id'

Comment: This menu is created in wp-admin section under appearance>menu

Comment: So the name primary? If yes it is still not working
https://imgur.com/a/aRV2F

Comment: Got the code here:
Functions.php: https://pastebin.com/P5CuraLX
header.php: https://pastebin.com/bjSpHamL

Answer (score 0):

Wordpress menu will instantiate a menu object - you've literally got the html of the menu there, but this should be:

```
    <nav id="site-navigation" class="main-navigation mobile-navigation">
        <!-- <button class="menu-toggle" aria-controls="primary-menu" aria-expanded="false"><?php //esc_html_e( 'Primary Menu', 'eldon' ); ?></button> -->
        <?php
            wp_nav_menu( array(
                'theme_location' => 'menu-1',
                'menu_id'        => 'primary-menu',
            ) );
        ?>
    </nav><!-- #site-navigation -->
```

The menu should alreayd be set in the backend of the installation which will refer to this point in the header template.

Look here https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress/tree/master/wp-content/themes for examples of header.php templates using WordPress conventions. Please always refer to the Codex - you need to make sure you're not breaking a theme!

https://codex.wordpress.org/Theme_Development

Best thing you can do is to download a fresh copy of WordPress from wordpress.org and try again. You shouldn't have to change these templates but if you do, make sure you do it properly :)